# MonetDB database shut down error

Tags: monetdb

After cleaning up some tables in MonetDB, trying to connect to mclient and getting kicked out.

`monetdbd: internal error while starting mserver, please refer to the logs`

merovingian.log -> 

`2017-02-16 16:40:54 MSG ame[1672]: # MonetDB 5 server v11.21.13 "Jul2015-SP2"
2017-02-16 16:40:54 MSG ame[1672]: # Serving database 'ame', using 8 threads
2017-02-16 16:40:54 MSG ame[1672]: # Compiled for x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/64bit with 64bit OIDs and 128bit integers dynamically linked
2017-02-16 16:40:54 MSG ame[1672]: # Found 29.453 GiB available main-memory.
2017-02-16 16:40:54 MSG ame[1672]: # Copyright (c) 1993-July 2008 CWI.
2017-02-16 16:40:54 MSG ame[1672]: # Copyright (c) August 2008-2015 MonetDB B.V., all rights reserved
2017-02-16 16:40:54 MSG ame[1672]: # Visit http://www.monetdb.org/ for further information
2017-02-16 16:40:54 MSG ame[1672]: # Listening for UNIX domain connection requests on mapi:monetdb:///ebs_data/monetdb/ame/.mapi.sock
2017-02-16 16:40:54 MSG ame[1672]: # Start processing logs sql/sql_logs version 52200
2017-02-16 16:40:54 MSG merovingian[1233]: database 'ame' (1672) has exited with exit status 1
2017-02-16 16:40:59 ERR merovingian[1233]: client error: database 'ame' appears to shut itself down after starting, check monetdbd's logfile for possible hints`

I can't find any other logs. There is nothing in `sql/sql_logs`.